# Count percentage of column with GROUP BY

Tags: postgresql, group-by, count, cte, window-functions

Consider the following query:

```sql
SELECT
  country
  , count(id) AS "count"
FROM
  lead
WHERE
  date_part('year', lead.since) = date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY "country"
ORDER BY "count" DESC
;
```

It returns something like:

```
country count
fr  3456
us  569
sc  248
…
```

How can I add a third column with the percentage of the total count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT country, 
       COUNT(id) "count",
       COUNT(id) / SUM(COUNT(id)) OVER () * 100 percent
FROM lead
WHERE date_part('year', lead.since) = date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY "count" DESC;
```

Comment: what does `SUM(COUNT(id)) OVER()` do in this case? I find it hard to understand.

Comment: @jdhao `COUNT(id)` counts `id` values with current GROUP BY expression. `SUM(COUNT(id)) OVER()` gets the sum of these values over the whole output rowset - i.e. it counts total count for all `id` values.